# {VIRTUALBOX} Ubuntu Linux -32bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am attempting to run 32-bit Ubuntu Linux on my computer with virtualbox, the host OS is windows XP. After hours upon hours, i've figured out how to work virtualbox. I started Ubuntu linux, and saw the loading screen. After minutes of that, i get a screen of random color strips, and what i beleive are their hexidecimal codes. I can't get past it, does anyone have a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's a 32-bit version you've installed? How did you install it? Did you load the Ubuntu LiveCD?

Comment: @AFH Now that i think about it, i never checked. I downloaded it via the official Ubuntu Site: http://www.ubuntu.com/download .

Comment: @AFH Thank you, i had downloaded the 64-bit version.

Comment: OK, I'll summarise our discussion in an answer for others who may encounter similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I mostly use VMplayer, I've had no problems with running 32-bit VMs on XP.

I checked your link from the [Ubuntu down-load site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) that you gave in our discussion. Unless you follow the links to alternative versions, you will get the 64-bit version by default.

I've never tried to see the effect of running a 64-bit VM on a 32-bit host, but your symptoms are the sort of thing I would expect when trying to run invalid instructions. I've seen similar when I've have had corrupt boot sectors.

Our discussion confirms that you have installed the 64-bit version.